# SQL query: how to convert data to numbers only when it does not contains letters

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, integer, varchar

While extracting ERP products' references from SQL server, it is extracted as text.
These references sometimes contains only numbers, and sometimes it contains numbers + the letters CN.
I would like to extract it as a number when it only contains numbers, and as a text if it contains the letters CN. Unfortunately, I did not find a way to do it.

This is what I tried ("INVMB.MB110" being the the field "Reference" in the SQL server):

```
SELECT
CASE 
WHEN INVMB.MB110 LIKE '%CN%' 
THEN INVMB.MB110 
ELSE CAST(INVMB.MB110 AS INT) END 
AS 'Reference'
```

I was expecting to convert to integer only if the reference does not contain 'CN', but it seems it tries to convert it in any case. Here is the error message I get:

> Failed converting varchar value '30903CN013 ' to data type int.

Comment: A case expressions all THEN values must have compatible data types. This means your `THEN INVMB.MB110` implicitly is casted to int.

Comment: " I would like to extract it as a number when it only contains numbers, and as a text if it contains the letters" what does that mean? A column can have only one data type, which do you want?

Comment: @Charlieface, thanks for this information. If I have to choose a data type, then I would need integer. Still, how would this work with data containing letters?

Comment: It won't. You can't store letters and punctuation in a number column. You need to decide whether you want to return that. You could just return `NULL` eg `SELECT TRY_CAST(INVMB.MB110 AS INT) AS Reference`

Comment: I think you need to re-think what you actually want. Why does type of column matters to you? You can't put both string and int into same column, unless it's string, which takes you back to where you started. Do you plan on doing something with the data or what's the next step of your operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two columns one for the string data and one for the numeric data. Assuming you have SQL Server 2016 or higher you can use the `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_PARSE` function.

```
SELECT
    [INVMB.MB110_INT] = TRY_CONVERT(INT, [INVMB.MB110])
    ,[INVMB.MB110_STRING] = [INVMB.MB110]
    ,[IsNumberDataType] = CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(INT, [INVMB.MB110]) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

The `TRY_CONVERT` function will convert the string to a numeric if it is possible otherwise it will return NULL.

Note that the `TRY_CONVERT` function will return a numeric value of 0 if the source string is an empty string.  If you don’t want 0 to be retuned for an empty string, the use the `TRY_PARSE` function.

If you absolutely require the values in a single column, you can convert the values to a SQL_VARIANT types (after you converted the string to the desired base type). I personally avoid SQL_VARIANT types like the plague, there is just too many performance and implicit conversion issues associated with them. I have included an example of a query that returns some sample data.

```
WITH VariantSampleData
AS
(
    SELECT 
        variant_value = TRY_CONVERT(SQL_VARIANT, TRY_CONVERT(INT, '123') )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        variant_value = TRY_CONVERT(SQL_VARIANT, 'abc' )
)
SELECT
    variant_value
    ,BaseType = SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(variant_value,'BaseType')
    ,[math] = TRY_CONVERT(INT, variant_value) + 1
FROM
    VariantSampleData
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I guess what I wanted to do is not doable without having seral columns as you propose.

Comment: @Luc-OlivierPineau you can use sql_variant data type to store different data types in one column, but to perform any operation on the values, you still need to convert the variant back to the base data type. There is also a lot of performance overheads when using a sql_variant and you will probably run into all sorts of implicit conversion issues when querying out your data.